# How to split and extract multispectral imagery in QGIS (2.18)

Tags: qgis, raster

I am looking for a way to split multiband images and extract all the bands at once- instead of subsetting one band at a time.

Is there any method in QGIS which could allow for this? I know there are split RGB band tools but I have 8 band files.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split image` tool from Orfeo toolbox. The Split Image, as you can see below, will split the multiband image that you have into separate images.

[image]

You need to specify an output filename. The output filename will be used to get the prefix and the extension of the output images to write.

In the example above, I just put `Image.tif`. You can choose any name you prefer.

However, Orfeo toolbox is not downloaded by default into QGIS. You need to download it separately, or better use OSGeo4W advanced install to download Orfeo toolbox from there.

Comment: Hey Ahmad- thanks! I have tried installing orfeo in the past with no success. I will however try OSGeo4W to see how that works. I will let you know.