# Extracting some bands of multiband satellite image as layers using QGIS 3

Tags: raster, qgis-3, extract

I have a multiband(8 bands) satellite image. Now what I want, is to extract 5 bands from that image. By extraction I mean saving those 5 bands into a different layer or Geotiff. I am using QGIS 3 (Madeira) and Ubuntu 16.04.

I am avoiding the use of extra tools and trying to keep to in-built tools in QGIS.

Comment: I believe you can use the rearrange bands tool to select each band individually and save them to a new file. As suggested here actually: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/314248/97475

Comment: Can i extract one or more bands from multi band raster using python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for **Rearrange Bands** in your processing toolbox. It will appear within GDAL Raster Conversion Tools.

Select your multiband input raster and specify the bands you would like to "extract" within "Selected band(s)". Do further settings if you wish like choosing data type or the new order of your selected bands and run the tool. The newly created raster will only contain the bands you have specified within "Selected band(s)".

[image]